# Equivalent definitions of Chern classes

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

I have met two different definitions for Chern classes and I am wondering how are they all the same?

The first one is from Jöran Schlömer's book and they define the Chern class of a complex vector bundle $E \to M$ via the coefficients of $\det\left(tI - \frac{1}{2\pi i}A\right)= \sum_{k=0}^n f_k(A)t^{n-k}$ by setting $$c_k(E) = [f_k(\Omega)]$$ where $\Omega$ is the curvature matrix. The problem I have with this one is that I think it should be $$c_k(E) = \left[f_k\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i} \Omega\right)\right]$$ instead, but I'm no longer entirely sure.

The second definition is by Tu  and he states that the Chern classes are obtained from $$\det\left(I + \frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega\right)=1+c_1(E)+\dots+c_n(E).$$

This I think is the total Chern class instead? If anyone could elaborate on why these two should give me back the same thing and whether or not it should be $$c_k(E) = [f_k(\Omega)]$$ or $$c_k(E) = \left[f_k\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i} \Omega\right)\right]$$ I would be glad. I think this might be due to some sign conventions.

Comment: The definitions agree. Note that $c_j(E)\in H^{2j}(M)$, and this “weight” corresponds to the coefficient of $t^{n-j}$. With the coefficient $i/2\pi$ of $\Omega$ you get the correct polynomial in $\Omega$; you do not want further factors. Write this out explicitly for, say, the tautological line bundle on $\Bbb CP^1$ and check.

Comment: The reason I'm confused is because Tu defines Pontrjagin classes as $$p_k(E) = \left[f_{2k}\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega\right)\right] \in H^{4k}(M)$$  and this has the extra $i/2\pi$ factor. Shouldn't the Chern class be nothing more than $$c_k(E) = \left[f_{k}\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}\Omega\right)\right] \in H^{2k}(M)?$$ @TedShifrin

Comment: This is definitely wrong. There's also a sign question, since $p_k(E)=(-1)^kc_{2k}(E\otimes\Bbb C)$, ordinarily.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't have Tu's book but for what it's worth Bott and Tu use the non-standard convention in their book and just set $p(E)=c(E\otimes\Bbb C)$

Comment: @pancini Ah, I'd forgotten about that. I don't have Tu's book, either. But the extra $i/2\pi$ factor is clearly not compatible with that, regardless of sign. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two formulas are exactly the same, with no sign difference.

For your concern of the first definition, the $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ is contained in his definition of $f_k(A)$, so he didn't need to write it again.

Yes, the second one is the total Chern class. Just let $t=1$, you match it with the first one, note
$$
\frac{i}{2\pi} = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I ask what do you mean by $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ being contained in his definition of $f_k(A)$? That it's actually $f_k\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i} A\right)$? I could not find this mentioned in the book. @three-aggies

Comment: It would also seem that $p_k(E)=(-1)^kc_{2k}(E\otimes\Bbb C)$ is no longer valid with this definition.

Comment: For the first question, I mean if the equation were $\det(tI-A)=\sum_{k=0}^n g_k(A)t^{n-k}$, then we have $f_k(A) = g_k(\frac{1}{2\pi i} A)$. It is this $g_k(A)$ that is algebraically the more familiar elementary symmetric functions of the eigenvalues of $A$, but $f_k(A)$ in the definition of the book has all the powers of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ thrown in already. Indeed, $f_k(A) = (\frac{1}{2\pi i})^k g_k(A)$.

Comment: For the Pontryagin class, I think again it goes back to the definition. There seem to be two different ways to go: either do $\det(−\frac{1}{2\pi}B)$ or $\det(−\frac{1}{2\pi i}B)$. Here $B$ is skew-symmetric, so only the even degree ones are non-zero. The first one would produce $p_k(E) = (-1)^k c_{2k}(E\otimes {\mathbb C})$. The second one would produce one without sign. It seems the first one is more standard, since in real bundles, there should not be an $i$ anyway.

Comment: Can you explain how did you manage to factor out the $(\frac{1}{2\pi i})^k$ from $g_k(\frac{1}{2\pi i} A)$? @three-aggies

Comment: $g_k(A)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$, that is, it is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$ in terms of the elements of the matrix $A$. (It is the sum of the principal $k$-minors of $A$, up to a sign.)